# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'execute': For input string: "1#1"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have the following method declaration:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 ? * MON#1")
protected synchronized void execute() {...}
```

But my application startup fails and I see following error in logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'execute': For input string: "1#1"
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:461) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

How to correct it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887822/spring-cron-vs-normal-cron

Comment: Does springframework recognizes the pattern `MON#1`?

Comment: @gtgaxiola, looks like not, actually I don't what does it mean

Comment: It means the first Monday of the month. But I do not know why Spring doesn't use that format.

Comment: @gstackoverflow does my answer make sense?

Answer (score 6):

The error occurs when the cron expression is not recognizable by Spring boot. Should probably due to the  `MON#1` part.

[Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) and [This post](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions) might be useful to find the correct cron expression in Spring boot.

Some examples from the documentation :

> ```
> "0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
> "*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
> "0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
> "0 0 8,10 * * *" = 8 and 10 o'clock of every day.
> "0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30 and 10 o'clock every day.
> "0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
> "0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
> ```

And from the post (with seconds included):

> At 12:00 p.m. (noon) every day:
> `0 0 12 * * ?`
>
> Every five minutes starting at 1 p.m. and ending at 1:55
> p.m. and then starting at 6 p.m. and ending at 6:55 p.m., every day:
> `0 0/5 13,18 * * ?`
>
> Every minute starting at 1 p.m. and ending at 1:05
> p.m., every day:
> `0 0-5 13 * * ?`
>
> At 1:15 p.m. and 1:45 p.m. every Tuesday in the month of
> June:
> `0 15,45 13 ? 6 Tue`
>
> At 9:30 a.m. every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,
> Thursday and Friday:
> `0 30 9 ? * MON-FRI`
>
> At 9:30 a.m. on the 15th day of every month:
> `0 30 9 15 * ?`
>
> At 6 p.m. on the last day of every month:
> `0 0 18 L * ?`
>
> At 6 p.m. on the third to last day of every month:
> `0 0 18 L-3 * ?`
>
> At 10:30 a.m. on the last Thursday of every month:
> `0 30 10 ? * 5L`
>
> At 10 a.m. on the third Monday of every month:
> `0 0 10 ? * 2#3`
>
> At 12 midnight on every day for five days starting on the
> 10th day of the month:
> `0 0 0 10/5 * ?`