# Unable to run schedular cron expression with 7 fields

Tags: java, spring, task

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/20 * * * * ? 2005")
    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("ITs running...");
    }
```

Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'execute': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7 in "0/20 * * * * ? 2005")

When I am trying to use 7 fields within the cron expression I am getting this error. Could anyone help me to resolve this issue please?

Comment: see this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521238/8098322

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) supports six fields when using cron expression. As per [`CronSequenceGenerator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) docs it doesn't support a year field:

> The pattern is a list of six single space-separated fields: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names.

Comment: thanks you. But is there any other way to make use of year field in the cron expression?

Comment: @preetk not with `@Scheduled` unless you plan to fork Spring and add the support yourself

Comment: Example Unix Format:   0 56 8 1/1 * * *
Example Spring Format: 0 56 8 1/1 * *